# Magento2: Email checkout validation on submit only

Tags: magento2, checkout, validation

Is it possible to trigger the validation of email field when the customer click next button only? I want to remove the validation on keypress etc

Answer (score 0):

Added following code inside next event method

```
var loginFormSelector = 'form[data-role=email-with-possible-login]';
$(loginFormSelector).validation();
var emailValidationResult = Boolean($(loginFormSelector + ' input[name=username]').valid());
if(emailValidationResult) {
    // validation
}
```